# Count one cross join, sum another inside T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a query for our incident management software that will report, for each engineer, the number of request they closed today and the time logged on actions today. The data is stored in four main tables:

- People - names and IDs of the engineers
- ArchiveRequests - support requests
- ArchiveReqSLA -   time-releated details for requests
- ArchiveActions -  Actions on requests

This is the query I have come up with so far:

```
SELECT FirstName,
    LastName,
    count(ArchiveRequests.RequestId) AS TicketsClosed,
    SUM(TimeUsed) AS TimeUsed
FROM ArchiveRequests
INNER JOIN People        ON ArchiveRequests.AssignedToId = People.PersonId
INNER JOIN ArchiveReqSLA ON ArchiveReqSLA.RequestId      = ArchiveRequests.RequestId
WHERE
    CONVERT(date, Closed)  = @Date
AND ArchiveRequests.StatusId IN (
    SELECT StatusId
    FROM Status
    WHERE Closed = 1
)
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

This works wonderfuly, and generates the following:

```
Name    Tickets
Mr X    16
Ms Y    11
Mr Z    10
...
```

I then went to add the time spent, and came up with the following:

```
SELECT FirstName,
    LastName,
    COUNT(ArchiveRequests.RequestId) AS Tickets,
    SUM(TimeUsed) AS TimeUsed
FROM ArchiveRequests
INNER JOIN People         ON ArchiveRequests.AssignedToId = People.PersonId
INNER JOIN ArchiveReqSLA  ON ArchiveReqSLA.RequestId      = ArchiveRequests.RequestId
INNER JOIN archiveActions ON ArchiveActions.ActionedById  = People.PersonId
WHERE
    CONVERT(date, ArchiveActions.ActionDate) = @Date
AND CONVERT(date, Closed)                    = @Date
AND ArchiveRequests.StatusId IN (
    SELECT StatusId
    FROM Status
    WHERE Closed = 1
)
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

However this returns numbers that are far too high, and breaks the ticket numbers as well:

```
Name   Tickets  Time
Mr X   416      2064
Ms Y   290      2010
Mr Z   242      2574
```

What happened to my results?

Comment: The way I see it, there are N rows in `archiveActions ` table for each row in `People` table. You have to narow your join by adding another condition. Otherwise, for each person you select all actions in the history table.

Comment: `INNER JOIN archiveActions ON ArchiveActions.ActionedById  = People.PersonId ` you miss a relation to request on this one

Comment: hm, only a guess, but try inner join (Select distinct actionedbyid, sum(TimeUsed) from archiveactions where CONVERT(date, .ActionDate) = @Date group by actionedbyid) as a on a,actionedby = People.personid
You would have to remove the sum and where statement from the outer query

Comment: I think there should be a join between ArchiveRequests.RequestId and some column from archiveActions table

Comment: @kl78 Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 17
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'A'.

Comment: @kl78 Fixed that issue, which gives correct ticket numbers, however the time is still off (unless people started working 33 hour days)

Comment: yes you need to give the sum a alias, sum(TimeUsed) as timeused, if you get 33h working day, maybe something in table archiveactions is wrong or there is another condition you have to look for, you get the sum for a specific person for a specific day from the subquery, so this should be correct

Comment: @kl78 right, I know what's happening with that now. It's tickets that were opened before @ Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a join for this. This is what you want to do:

1. report, for each engineer,

   1. the engineer details,
2. the number of request they closed today

   1. The number of Requests
   2. which that person
   3. Closed today
3. the time logged on actions today

   1. the total time
   2. by them
   3. on actions today

So translate it directly to SQL as follows:

```
select 
  -- 1.1. engineer details
  p.PersonId, p.firstname, p.lastname,
  -- 2. the number of request they closed today
  (
    -- 2.1 the number of requests
    select count(1) 
    from ArchiveRequests ar 
    -- 2.2 By that person
    where ar.AssignedToId = p.personId
    -- 2.3 closed today
    and CONVERT(date, Closed) = @Date
  ) as TicketsClosed,
  -- 3. The time logged today
  (
    select sum(TimeUsed)
    from ArchiveActions aa
    where aa.ActionedById = p.PersonId
    and CONVERT(date, aa.actionDate) = @date
  ) as TimeUsed
-- 1. report, for each engineer, 
from People p
```

Comment: I had to add an INNER JOIN to pull in ArchiveReqSLA (to get the Closed column), but this has the same issues as kl78's answer. I think I need to do this as two queries. One for tickets closed today, one for actions completed today

Comment: @CyberJacob, this is three queries, the queries in brackets are called subqueries, each one does what you describe: One for tickets closed today one for actions completed today.